# How to convert string value to an integer in MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

In my NodeJs application I am using MongoDB database. I have two collections `products` and `market_companies`. Both collections have a field name `hub_id` and `dimensions`, and here `dimensions` is an object field.

I have created the aggregation pipeline where in both the collections I am comparing `hub_id` and `dimensions` field but the thing is `hub_id` in `products` collection is an `integer` but in `market_companies` it's an `string` due to which I am not getting desired output.

I want to know how can I convert `hub_id` to integer from string in `market_companies` collection.

Below is my code:

```js
     db.products.aggregate([
    {
    $lookup: {
      from: "market_companies",
      let: {
        hubId: "$hubId",
        dimensions: "$dimensions"
      },
      as: "companies",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$hubId", // How to convert this into Integer
                    "$$hubId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $setEquals: [
                    {
                      "$objectToArray": {
                        $ifNull: [
                          "$dimensions",
                          {}
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "$objectToArray": {
                        $ifNull: [
                          "$$dimensions",
                          {}
                        ]
                       }
                     }
                   ]
                 }
               ]
             }
           }
         },
       ]
      }
     }
    ])
```

Comment: Hi, please try to edit your question to include more details, such as the language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [$toInt](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) operator:

```
{
  $eq: [
    { $toInt: "$hubId" },
    "$$hubId"
  ]
},
```